# Configure Ember CLI to use http-mock

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

The setup:

```
ember new shop
cd shop
ember install:addon ember-cli-scaffold
ember generate scaffold product name:string available:boolean
ember generate adapter product
```

I'd like to use http-mock but http://www.ember-cli.com/#ember-data tells me to do this:

```
ember g http-mock products
```

After that I use this code to generate two example products:

**server/mocks/products.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var productsRouter = express.Router();

  productsRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send({
      'products': [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: 'Orange',
        available: true
       }, {
        id: "2",
        name: 'Apple',
        available: false
        }
      ]
    });
  });

  [...]
```

When I use the command `ember server` and browse to http://localhost:4200/products I see nothing.

What am I missing? What else do I have to start or to configure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get this thing flying the adapter has to be changed as follows.

**app/adapters/product.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  'namespace': 'api'
});
```

Comment: I didn't. I just replayed the example code to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

wadeo: @wintermeyer have you tried http://localhost:4200/api/products

Comment: I can download the JSON there. But how can I tell the Ember app to use this?

Comment: You will have to do two things... You will need to make changes in your route for each of the pages that will utilize this api and make a call to the mock data source in your page template. Lets say you have a page called products you wll need to make changes to your route.... `import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model:function() {
            return this.store.findAll('listing');
        }
});`
Also make changes to your products.hbs `

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do two things... You will need to make changes in your route for each of the pages that will utilize this api and make a call to the data source in your page template. Lets say you have a page called products you will need to make changes to your route....

```
// routes/products.js

import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model:function() {
            return this.store.findAll('product');
        }
});
```

Also make changes to your template:

```
// products.hbs

{{#each products in model}}
   <li > {{proudct._id}} - {{#link-to 'product' product}}Details{{/link-to}}</li>{{/each}}
```